# Bezier Curve. following but not in sync

Tags: bezier-curves

[image: Wont follow]Alright so, it follows the curve but they wont follow in line, they will all rotate at the same time not following the line, the primary will follow it but the rest in the array will copy the first and not follow the array correctly.

Comment: Im going to assume no one is going to give me assistance... Why did i ever ask on this website then

Comment: What follows the curve? They? Primary and the rest? An array of what? What do you mean by sync? Please edit your question and explain clearly what you are trying to do. Add images that might help others understand.

Comment: Just added picture

Comment: move the array modifier above the curve modifier

Comment: Omg i got an answer holy cow, 36 minutes later, Thank you.

Comment: If you want quicker answers, please consider being more specific in your question. Guidelines here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask